# How to delegate authority authoritative-only name servers

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

I would like guidance on how to delegate authority for my own authoritative-only nameservers without resolving to use **A glued record** with the registrar.

I ask this as I have one static public ip and the registrar requires two separate static public ips.

Is there a way to propagate the nameservers without recurring to the registrar?

Comment: Use a DNS Hoster with a robot/web fronted. If you need your own DMS you can set it up as a hidden primary. There is really no reason to risk slow and flaky DNS with your single IP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two separate IPs but **at least two separate** *authoritative* name **servers on separate networks**. This is for ensuring the availability of the service when one server or network is down; when your authoritative name servers aren't responding your whole domain is down.

From [IANA Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements):

> **Network diversity**
>
> The name servers must be in at least two
>   topologically separate networks. A network is defined as an origin
>   autonomous system in the BGP routing table. The requirement is
>   assessed through inspection of views of the BGP routing table.

Instead of trying to sweep the problem under the carpet by setting the same IP address on two glue records, use a real solution and add separate secondary DNS servers.

You don't need to have two own servers for this, though. There are many services provided for *secondary authoritative DNS*. Many registrar, VPS provider and ISP has an included or inexpensive service for this. Your registrar being **GoDaddy**, you don't need a new service provider for secondary DNS. Instead, you can easily just [Enable Secondary DNS with GoDaddy nameservers as slaves](https://www.godaddy.com/help/enable-secondary-dns-with-godaddy-nameservers-as-slaves-23911) (from `[+]` DOMAINS > Action > Manage DNS > Advanced Features > Secondary DNS). Remember to allow zone transfers from GoDaddy slaves `72.167.238.111` & `72.167.238.110` and add them to your zone (`IN NS xfr03.domaincontrol.com.` & `xfr04.domaincontrol.com.`), too.

You always set your nameservers at the registrar, whether they need *glue records* (name servers on the same domain i.e. `example.com. IN NS ns1.example.com.`) or not (name servers on another domain i.e. `example.com. IN NS ns1.example.org.`). Glue records are needed to prevent *circular references* in the first case. Here, the registrar sets this ***delegation*** for you:

> **Consistency between delegation and zone**
>
> The set of NS records served by the authoritative name servers must
>   match those proposed for the delegation in the parent zone.

The registrar just does these checks to conform to the IANA requirements in the linked article.

Comment: thanks for the information, the problem is that Godaddy is not allowing glued records referencing to the same static public IP anymore, hence I got stuck on this aspect. Can you recommend a service provider that be used as a secondary authoritative DNS, pls and my ISP has not service in that regard.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning your registrar. I've used another for more than a decade and I'm satisfied with their service, but I don't want to advertise any service provider here. Luckily, your registrar has this service included, too. I added that information to my answer.

Comment: sorry my fault, the domain in question is registered with a registrar that basically offers just basic dns services and the domain was an off-site DNS record with Godaddy. Is there a way I can do the manual propagation of my nameservers if I manage to get hold of a second static public IP

Comment: I don't understand how you were setting the glue records at GoDaddy, if it's not your registrar. Which registrar you are using?

Comment: For the domain in question, its with terranetwork. They offered to do the glue only if I get a reseller account which I basically would not need or use.

Comment: [TerraNetwork](https://www.terranetwork.net/) seems like a web hosting provider that actually uses [Enom](https://www.enom.com/) as a registrar, listed in [ICANN Accredited Registrars](https://www.icann.org/registrar-reports/accredited-list.html). However, if it's not possible with them, it seems that _FrontDam GmbH_ has a free DNS replication service, [BuddyDNS](https://www.buddyns.com/services/dns-replication/), limited to 0.3 Million queries/month. You could use it temporarily while planning on changing registrar.